# Метод ReduceRight

Tags: javascript

```js
// Входной массив
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
// Оставляем только чётные числа
let b = arr.filter(element => !(element % 2))
// Считаем квадратный корень и записываем в аккумулятор
let c = b.reduceRight((accumulator, element) => accumulator + Math.sqrt(element), 0); // 3.44*
console.log(b)
console.log(c)
```

Подскажите почему в accumulator записывается корень из 2 +корень из 4? А не 2 +корень из 4?

В аккумулятор же записывается первое значение к которому прибавляют в дальнейшем, почему оно в корне?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде установлено начальное значение `, 0);`. В этом случае оно и будет первым значением аккумулятора.

Также в коде использован [`.reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight), который обходит массив *с конца*

Чтобы в качестве начального значения брался первый элемент массива - нужно убрать этот параметр. Чтобы сложение было с первого элемента, вместо `reduceRight` нужно использовать `.reduce`

```js
// Входной массив
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
// Оставляем только чётные числа
let b = arr.filter(element => !(element % 2))
// Считаем квадратный корень и записываем в аккумулятор
let c = b.reduce((accumulator, element) => accumulator + Math.sqrt(element)); // 3.44*
console.log(b)
console.log(c)
```